# Magento2: Invoice and shipment emails are not going to the customer

Tags: invoice, magento2.3.1, transactional-mail, shipment

I am using Magento2.3.1.
I have installed mageplaza SMTP extension and configured it with Send Grid details. I have completed all configuration and able to sent test email successfully.

After that I have placed a test order using COD and I received new order email.
After this I have generate invoice and shipment for this order from admin > Sales > Order section (without tick "Email Copy of Shipment" option).

My customer not received any invoice and shipment email.

Any one let me know what is the issue and "Email Copy of Shipment" option required to tick for notified to customer via email about invoice and shipment.

Please let me know is this any code issue or any process issue for generating invoice and shipment from admin.

Thanks

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, "Email Copy of Shipment/Invoice/Creditmemo" is required to send emails. without that customer will never get emails of invoice,shipment,creditmemo.

please accept as a solution if you find it helpfull.:)

Answer (score 0):

It is not code issue but it is your process issue, you need to keep it ticked this option "Email Copy of Shipment" then only you will be able to get the emails.

Thanks
Vibhore

Answer (score 0):

It is required to tick the "Email Copy of Shipment" option in order to send the shipment email. It is default magento behaviour. I've noticed this same behavior on **Magento 2.4.1** also.

But this is not the case with invoice emails, it should work as expected. Check whether it is enabled or not under
`Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Invoice -> Enabled`.

In order to by default check the "Email Copy of Shipment" option on shipment creation page, use below code in your custom module.

Override default template with your custom template in

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::create/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to replace piece of code in default template with below code. I've added `checked="checked"`
`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtml`

```
<?php if ($block->canSendShipmentEmail()): ?>
<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option field-email">
    <input id="send_email"
           class="admin__control-checkbox"
           name="shipment[send_email]"
           value="1"
           type="checkbox"
           checked="checked"/>
    <label class="admin__field-label"
           for="send_email">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email Copy of Shipment')) ?></span></label>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you. Thanks!